Understanding pages in relation to heaps
I believe I am a little confused about what exactly a database page actually is, and perhaps also database heaps, and how they relate to each other.
From my understanding;

A database heap is a table which stores database pages, without using a clustered index.


Pages are more like the physical I/O representation of data. They exist to store records. They have fixed sizes and are thought of as a basic unit of I/O operation. They often contain multiple database rows.

I get that rows, (database) pages and (database) heaps are all abstract database concepts (for lack of a better description), but pages appear to be a more special case in that they "bridge" the final gap between the concept of a database as an abstraction of data, and the database and its data as a physical representation on the underlying physical disk.
But the fact that this "final" physical "bridge" exists within another abstract database concept is really confusing me. I would have expected this "bridge" to be the most bottom layer of all the database abstraction concepts. Basically the last thing that contains all other database abstractions.
I guess the only way I can understand this is if;

There exists another abstraction which persists the remaining database abstractions (what persists heap tables to disk, and whatever contains heap tables?)
Pages also persist the rows of heap tables, somewhere, which means pages persisting pages?

Or am I way off in my understanding? I am still learning, so while a technical deep dive is appreciated, a more simplified explanation at this stage would be enough.

No, a page is not an abstract concept. It is a concrete "physical I/O representation of data", as you wrote, containing the concrete representations of some rows in a record of fixed size.

I think I understand that aspect - its trying to wrap my head around the idea of that concrete representation being passed around within other abstract concepts (heaps, tables) which I'm struggling with.

There's a couple of different layers of abstraction, and also the difference between a logical construct and a physical construct.
In database systems typically at the highest level there are Tables that represent your data. Tables contain a construct known as Rows, which are a set of data. Each Row contains a specific related group of data points. Each of those data points are known as Columns. These are logical constructs.
Under the hood of the Table, there's a logical data structure that dictates how the data is stored and in which order that data is stored. More specifically, that data structure defines the logical order of the Rows. Most commonly in databases systems is two types of data structures, a B-Tree and a Heap (though there are even more data structures one can utilize in modern systems). A B-Tree stores the Rows sorted in order of the Column fields one specifies in its definition. A Heap, conversely, is an unordered data structure, and stores the data unsorted. These are also logical constructs.
The next layer of abstraction is at the disk level, so is considered a physical construct. Regardless of the data structure above used for your Tables, they all need a way to be physically represented on disk. This representation is known as data Pages. They are a fixed size linear grouping of the Rows of data, stored on disk. (Think of it akin to a page in a phone book, with all the names and phone numbers.) When data is loaded off disk, the relevant Pages of data are located and loaded into Memory typically, and then the specific Rows from those Pages are processed and returned to the client query asking for those Rows. Not every Row in a Page will always be relevant to the query that is executing, and so that subset of Rows in the Page won't necessarily be used.
One of the purposes of Pages is to physically utilize the space on disk efficiently by filling up a certain area of the disk with related data. It also allows the database system to efficiently load data into Memory with a bigger unit of measure (the Page) as opposed to performing the same operation multiple times to load individual Rows into Memory. Think of it like building a sand castle, and each grain of sand is a Row, and your bucket to carry the sand is a Page. It would be very inefficient to pick up one grain of sand (one Row) at a time, and rather using a bucket (a Page) to pickup a bunch of sand at once is much more efficient and requires less operations to build the sand castle, even if you end up with leftover sand you didn't use, in your bucket, when you're done building the sand castle.
So to summarize, top down, it goes: Table -> Rows -> Data Structure (B-Tree, Heap, other kinds) -> Page -> Disk

A page is the fundamental unit of data storage. In unix systems page also referred to as block.For most of the database systems this is 8KB in size. But this can be modified for certain database systems like Oracle and PostgreSQL during setup but for SQL Server there is no straight forward ways I believe.
When it comes to tables, a table have data pages as well as index pages. For SQL Server when the table have a clustered index, the data page is a clustered index page if not it's a heap page or heap block. So heap is a data structure contains lot of pages scattered in the storage, hence there is no guarantee that the physical order of pages follow logical order of data. If you have secondary index or a non-clustered index then it has index pages pointing to clustered index pages if it is clustered or else pointing to heap blocks.
A table may have multiple columns each of different size and depends on the total size of a row, one or more rows fit into a single data page also called row density. But for certain columns with type like VARCHAR(max),TEXT, NTEXT etc they are considered as LOB as stored off-row not in actual data pages.
Another approach to the traditional rowstore is the columnar implementation used in analytical databases, where a single data page stores one or more entries of a single column, rather than storing whole row including all columns. This mostly match with query pattern in analytical databases where aggregations are over one or few columns and rest of the columns are not needed.
